# How to check test isssues on selenium server

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-grid

I deployed the selenium grid and ran tests on it. My tests failed but if I run them locally they completed successfully. How can see an image during running tests on the selenium grid node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using [official Selenium docker images](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium) in your grid, you can [connect to your node](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium#using-a-vnc-client) with [any VNC viewer](https://www.jihosoft.com/tips/vnc-client-viewer-windows-mac-linux.html) using port `5900` (if not changed in configuration) and password `secret`.

You can also try to [set up video recording](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium#video-recording-) of your scenario. But the former approach is simpler.

Comment: With Selenium Grid v4 official docker images, it also has noVNC built in, which allows you to view what is happening via your local browser: `http://<selenium-grid-address>:<host port>`. Just configure your host port to 7900 on each browser node container, i.e. `7901:7900`, os your url would be `http://<selenium-grid-address>:7901`. Also ensure that you have not configured the browser to be headless. As above the password is also `secret`.

Answer (score 0):

In VMs, Screen size will be small, please run your test with (1040, 740) VM screensize in your local. i hope you can identify your issue locally.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
options.addArguments("--window-size=1040,784");   // vm size : --window-size=1040,784
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```